# How to draw line between two circle in html canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I am a beginner to HTML canvas and i am trying to create a design where i can create a horizontal line between two circle here is the canvas that i wanted until now i cant figure out how do i join this two circle with a line

```js
//Script to draw the canvas 
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("c1");
var canvasobj = canvas1.getContext("2d");
canvasobj.lineWidth = 10;
canvasobj.beginPath();
canvasobj.strokeStyle = "red";
canvasobj.fillStyle = "orange";
canvasobj.arc(100, 100, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
canvasobj.moveTo(100, 0);
canvasobj.lineTo(100, 240);
canvasobj.stroke();
canvasobj.fill();
canvasobj.beginPath();
canvasobj.moveTo(5000, 0);
canvasobj.lineTo(0, 0);
canvasobj.stroke();
canvasobj.beginPath();
canvasobj.arc(500, 100, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
canvasobj.moveTo(500, 0);
canvasobj.lineTo(500, 240);
canvasobj.stroke();
canvasobj.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" class="drawncanvas" width="1500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/daz_001/kvw4n9pu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to connect the circle by line we need two input for line drawing one is beginning point and ending point. So we can get the two point from center of the circle point which we used to draw circle. one more thing is to note here is to connect the two by outer are of circle instead from the center so we need to add or subtract the radius of the circle with line points.

```js
//Script to draw the canvas 
                    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("c1");
                    var canvasobj = canvas1.getContext("2d");
                    canvasobj.lineWidth = 10;
                    canvasobj.beginPath();
                    canvasobj.strokeStyle ="red";
                    canvasobj.fillStyle="orange";
                    canvasobj.arc(100,100,60,0,2*Math.PI);
                    canvasobj.moveTo(100,0);
                    canvasobj.lineTo(100,240);
                    canvasobj.stroke();
                    canvasobj.fill(); 
                    canvasobj.beginPath();
                    canvasobj.moveTo(5000,0);
                    canvasobj.lineTo(0,0);
                    canvasobj.stroke();
                    canvasobj.beginPath();
                    canvasobj.arc(500,100,60,0,2*Math.PI);
                    canvasobj.moveTo(500,0);
                    canvasobj.lineTo(500,240); canvasobj.stroke();
                    canvasobj.fill();
                    canvasobj.beginPath();
                    canvasobj.moveTo(160,100); // this is the begining point of the line (x,y)
                    canvasobj.lineTo(440,100);// this is the ending point of the line (x,y)
                    
                    //if you want to connect two circle by outer area. In the begining point we need to add the circle radius with x value also need to reduce the x value from ending point
                    canvasobj.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" class="drawncanvas"  width="1500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
```

[Updated fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kvw4n9pu/1/)